# How to get page number with the query string in the URL in WordPress

Tags: wordpress, url, pagination, query-string

I am trying to send different parameters in a URL and apply pagination to it in WordPress on the front end, but I can't get the page now with `get_query_var()`.

Here is the link:

http://local.ismartcareers.com/category-jobs/page/2/?id=171599

Comment: have you registered the query_vars?

Answer (score 0):

You can retrieve the page number for any page simply by using

```
get_query_var('paged')
```